# Create a model that doesn't interact with database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm just wondering which is the 'best practice' in Laravel 5.2 to create a custom utility class.

I've read about the helpers inside App/Http/ that can be used by registering each file to the composer.json file. But I've also read that the helpers files should be plain functions files. Not classes.

So I'm wondering if creating a Model that is called File, which contains a series of methods to deal with files is the correct way to go. Since it has no interactions with the database, it should be named as the singular name of the table which is related right? But if i have no table called like that?

Isn't there any cleaner way to create classes which doesn't speak with the DB? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I would do it like you already kind of said, create a Helper class. However there already exist a File class in Laravel.

Comment: Ok, so it will be only a matter of name then. Easy fix. So it isn't true that the helpers MUST be only functions files? I'm reading about service providers, aren't they a good solution? Looks like you can create your own classes, register them and use them in your code...?

Comment: Helpers are just a name someone gave it to them. You can call it a service provider if you want, it does not change functionality :D. You can call it whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is absolutely fine to add new classes to your Laravel project that do not interact with the database and are not backed by an underlying database table.

If, for instance, you want to add a utility-style class named File, I would suggest adding this in `app/Utility/File.php`

You class definition would look something like this, as a result:

```
<?php
namespace App\Utility;

class File
{
    //methods and properties here
}
```

The composer autoloader will take care of finding the file for you, since you're placing the file inside Laravel's `App` namespace. Wherever you need to use the class, simply instantiate it like so:

```
$file = new \App\Utility\File();
```

Be wary of the [god object anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) when adding these kinds of utility classes. You should try and follow the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) whenever you can.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! This is really a great explanation! I was literally trying to build a god class. So if I've get quite well the single responsibility (which I've already heard and followed as long as i could) if I need to upload a file and check its ext there should be two classes right? One for the upload and one for the checks?

Comment: That's correct. In that situation you'd probably want 2 classes. One named `FileUpload` and another named `FileValidator`.
That said, Laravel does support this functionality out of the box, so you should read up on file uploads and validators before writing anything yourself. Don't reinvent the wheel!